# How do I set up nodes to use lightmaps?

Tags: shaders, lighting, texture-baking, baking

So I've exported textures and models from a game called Metal Gear Rising. I've assembled a scene. Now alongside the exported textures are the lightmap textures. How would I go about setting up nodes and such to use those lightmaps in Blender? I don't want to bake new ones, I just wanna use the ones from the game.

Comment: So you want to use the existing lightmaps and just mix them with the existing textures, right?

Comment: Yeah that's correct

Comment: Multiply (mix color node) diffuse color with lightmap and output as emission.